# Create custom report in Rally

Tags: rally

I would like to create a custom report in Rally which does the following:

- Show all the user stories which were added once the sprint started
- Show all the user stories which were moved/split into the next sprint

I wasn't able to work with the current options while trying to create a custom report. Would appreciate if someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

There is an app called Iteration Scope Change you can add to your dashboard or a custom page which will show a lot of these details.  It definitely will show items added/removed during the sprint.  Not sure on the second bullet, but it's worth trying it out and seeing if it meets your needs...